# How to add class to dynamically generated table in jquery?

Tags: javascript

I have written a javascript code to dynamically generate a table ,How can I add class attribute to genrated table?

I have tried using addClass(), and .className. But it did't work for me.

Here is my code :

```
var res = data.split("\n");
rows = res.length; 
var body = document.getElementById(name);
tbl  = document.createElement('table');
tbl.style.width  = '100px';
tbl.style.border = "1px solid black";

//tb1.class("table"); tb1.className="table" tn.addClass() ="table"          

for(var i = 1; i < rows; i++)
{
        var tr = tbl.insertRow();
        var column = res[i].split("@"); 

        cols = column.length;

        for(var j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            var td = tr.insertCell();
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(column[j]));
            td.style.border = "1px solid black";
        }
        }
        body.appendChild(tbl);
}
```

Comment: `I have written a jquery code` There is no jQuery there

Comment: I think your problem is your name is wrong -> 'tb1' instead 'tbl' // tbl.className = 'table'; should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute)

```
tbl.setAttribute('class', 'table')
```

Or you can use [`.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```js
const app = document.getElementById('app');

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
   const tbl = document.createElement('table');
   tbl.classList.add('class')
   app.appendChild(tbl)
})
```

```css
.class {
   border: 1px solid red;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<button id="button">Add</button>
```